# I have compiled this code but it says "could not find or load main class test3" **test3** is the name of file. The code is:

Tags: java

I have compiled this code but it says "could not find or load main class test3"
**test3** is the name of file.
The code is:

```
class TowDArray {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int twoD[][]=new int[4][5];
    int i,j,k=0;
    for (i=0;i<4;i++)
        for (j=0;j<5;j++) {
            twoD[i][j]=k;
            k++;
        }
    for (i=0;i<4;i++){
        for (j=0;j<5;j++)
            System.out.print(twoD[i][j]+" ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

Can you please tell me what the problem is

Comment: the problem is that the name of the class is `TowDArray` and not `test3`

Comment: For Java, the public class name and file name should be same. You should save this file as `TowDArray.java`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: Type the error message into Google and you will find the answer. Isn't that easier than creating a question on SO?

Comment: Are you sure that a better name isn't `TwoDArray`?

Answer (score 2):

First make the class public

```
public class TowDArray
```

Rename the file as

```
TowDArray.java
```

And try running it by

```
javac TowDArray.java
java TowDArray
```

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
java TowDArray
```

instead of

```
java test3
```